# Why is there one alignment on left, one on right, and one on left again?

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, amsmath

In this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&A B = C   \qquad &D E = F    \qquad &G H = I \qquad &K L M = N \\
&A B C = D \qquad &E F G = H  \qquad &I J K = L M
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

why is the first column aligned on left, the second on right, and the third on left?

How to have them always aligned on left (possibly by using `align*`, or a built-in environment but no new package)?

[image]

Comment: The number of `&`'s on each line is the `2n-1` where `n` is the number of alignment columns. So if there are 2 alignments we have 3 `&`'s and thus four coulumns aligned `right`, `left` (that's the first alignment pair), then `&` to separate the pair, then again `left`, `right` aligned (this is the second alignment pair). So on and so forth. You have four alignment columns here (you really should align on the `=`, it makes it easier to see what is going on. So you should have 7 `&` on each row, but you only have 4 (you are missing the `&`'s that separates the pairs)

Comment: you are not aligning the `=` so there really isn't any alignment needed here at all, so I would not use `align` or if you intended to align the `=` use  the usual, intended, markup `A B &= C` not `&A B = C` which is making an equation with no left hand side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your “first” column is actually the second.

That's how `align` works: it makes pairs of right/left aligned columns, and computes the space between the pairs according to some internal rules (there's a maximum separation, which is reduced if the display is crowded).

If you only want left aligned columns, just skip the odd numbered ones:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&A B = C    &&D E = F    &&G H = I      &&K L M = N \\
&A B C = D  &&E F G = H  &&I J K = L M
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is one thing to care about. If one of the expressions begins with an operator such as `\sum`, `\prod`, `\sin`, `\log` and so on, the alignment would be off on the left side; this is cured by adding `\!` after `&&` (or `&` in the first column pair). This is because `align` starts each even numbered column with `{}` which triggers a thin space before operators.